# How to show SSR of the residual vector from regression of y on X1 and X2 is equal to SSR of y on X1 and X2

Tags: econometrics, regression, applied-econometrics

What I mean in the title is that when we regress $y$ on $X_1$ and by using projection matrix $M_{X1}$
**how can I proceed with that:**

the model is
$$
y = X_1 \cdot \beta_1 + X_2 \cdot \beta_2 + u
$$

or as estimated version :

$$
y = X_1 \cdot b_1 + X_2 \cdot b_2 + e
$$
and residual vector comes from:
$$
\tilde{y} = M_{X1} \cdot y
$$

So to find that SSR of $\tilde{y}$ on  $X_1$ and $X_2$ is equal to SSR of ${y}$ on  $X_1$ and $X_2$

***How should I start? should I use Normal Equations ? or Should I create a linear relationship between some variables? or trying to multiply something with the inverse? I appreciate it if you can help or can give me a hint.***

Thanks.

Comment: What is the regression for the first SSR again? Is the regressand the residuals from the regression of $y$ on what? And the regressors for that regression is $X_1$ and $X_2$ or just $X_2$ or something else? Please clarify them.

Comment: we regress y on x1 and x2 and find residuals and SSR of regression of those residuals is equal to SSR of the regression of y on x1 and x2.

Comment: What do you mean by "SSR of regression of those residuals" above? Regression on what? Do you mean the regression of the residuals on x1 and x2 again?

Comment: If you mean (i) SSR from the regression of $\hat{u}$ on x1 and x2 versus (ii) SSR from the regression of y on x1 and x2, then you can use MM=M, where $M=I-P_X$. The residuals from (i) are $MMy$ and the residuals from (ii) are $My$, so they are identical.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about the notation. I started to take this course new but That is the thing I was looking for I guess.